# What is the best practice for creating customised graphical display of hierarchical data in WPF

Tags: wpf, tree, wpf-controls, custom-controls, hierarchical

I would like to be able to display network-tree information (stored in hierarchical data structure), as in the example shown in here:

[image]

In the diagram, I have a number of hosts (top-level nodes) - one of which is considered the 'Master' and therefore rendered differently from the other top-level nodes. Each node can have multiple sub-nodes (probes). The lines between the nodes show connections and if any of the connections goes down, the line changes as shown between Hostname2 and Probe2.3. Any node selected (host or probe) should also be rendered differently.

I am using Prism/MVVM and I'm trying to keep the code as clean as possible, but I'm not sure of the best way forward for displaying this data.

I have considered using a TreeView but I cannot think of a clean way of creating the links between nodes. I also considered creating a custom panel, but I'm not sure that's the most appropriate and wouldn't know where to start. Then I thought of creating a custom ItemsControl, as it would be nice to use the DataTemplate and HierarchicalDataTemplate.  I could also create a UserControl that contains a canvas and do everything in the code-behind there but it doesn't feel the best way.

I'd be grateful for opinions, example code, links or any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, last year I had to write something very similar for my current job.  I can't give you any of my code but I can lead you in the proper direction.

I found a directed graph collection class available here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574(v=vs.80).aspx#datastructures20_5_topic3.

I also use a Radial Panel I found on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771363(v=VS.90).aspx.  This allows multiple nodes to draw in a geometric shape.  So if you have 3 nodes, they draw a triangle, 4 a square, 5 a pentagon, etc...The more nodes you have, the more the layout becomes a circle.  This wouldn't work for you, but if you follow the link it shows you how to create a custom panel with a custom layout.  It could be beneficial.

I then used a Canvas as the stage, with the RadialPanel as the Canvas' child element.  Each node is just a WPF UserControl with an ellipses background that is added to the RadialPanel.  The directed graph collection then become a collection of node view models. I store where the node is connecting, almost like a linked list.  This allows me to traverse my graph collection easily without having to iterate each node to find the nodes I'm looking for.

There are some tricks involved in drawing to ensure the layout is proper, especially when drawing your connecting lines.  See this StackOverflow post I made:    [WPF and C# - Issue with GeneralTransform and UIElement.TransformToVisual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898908/wpf-and-c-sharp-issue-with-generaltransform-and-uielement-transformtovisual).  It has a link to an image of my node graph so you can compare our graphs.

This obviously isn't everything, but I think it's a good start.  For me, I couldn't really override any current controls to do exactly what I needed, so I went the hard way.  The trade off is a lot of work in the code-behind and view models, but I also control the major aspects of how it's drawn.  I this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not sure how I can make use of the  DataTemplate and HierarchalDataTemplate to retrieve the node and the child elements.